# Upgrade php 7.4.3 to php 7.4.8

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

When I am running **composer install** on my laravel project it requires php v 7.4.8 but on  my ubuntu system when I am installing php7.4 using **sudo apt install 7.4** it's installing the version 7.4.3 instead of latest php 7.4.8

I don't want to change the configuration composer.json because as it is not my personal project

How can I upgrade php version from 7.4.3 to 7.4.8

Comment: That will be because your distro has not caught up yet with PHP7.4.8, bit odd as thata year old now

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Assuming you did `apt update` and `apt upgrade` and that didn't help I recommend adding [this](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) repository (this link is for Ubuntu but this repository is also available for debian) this should allow you to install the latest versions of php in case the official repos that come with your linux distribution are lagging behind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to add thirdparty repository to install latest php version if it's not available in ubuntu main repository.
Run following commands to add repository and install php version:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y php7.4.8
```

Replace the version in the last command if you want to install any other version of php.